# static analysis without a file

Tags: python, static-analysis, pylint

I some 300,000 snippets of code, submitted by 700 students, which I have imported into a pandas data frame.

My goal is to run static analysis on all of these codes to find out what sort of errors they are facing. And I'm trying to do it without having to write these to actual files (300k files).

things I have tried :

directly calling pylint on data frame item

```
pl.run_pylint(['--errors-only',dt.iloc[0][0]])
```

and output is

```
    ************* Module number = int(input('Please enter a number: '));

if number < 0 {
    print(number*-1);
} else {
    print(number);
}
number = int(input('Please enter a number: '));

if number < 0 {
    print(number*-1);
} else {
    print(number);
}:1:0: F0001: No module named number = int(input('Please enter a number: '));

if number < 0 {
    print(number*-1);
} else {
    print(number);
} (fatal)
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1
```

whereas if I output the dataFrame content to a file, and run

```
pl.run_pylint(['--errors-only','test.py'])
```

the output is

```
************* Module test
test.py:1:15: E0001: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1) (syntax-error)
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

I'm actually out of ideas. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You might want to check out [`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile)

Comment: what is `dt.iloc[0][0]`? string-like representation of code?

Comment: hi dt.iloc[0] is a series and bloc[0][0] is a string representation of code

Answer (score 2):

I guess that is possible to run `pylint` programatically (eg. using `run_pylint` method), but under the hood `pylint` using subprocess to re-run lint as external command, so I used same way to run `pylint` as external command:

```py
from subprocess import run, PIPE

bad_code = '''
def a(a    =       1):
 print(       a     )
'''

result = run(['pylint', '--from-stdin', 'dummy.py'], input=bad_code.encode(), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

print('STDOUT ------------------')
print(result.stdout.decode("utf8"))
print('STDERR ------------------')
print(result.stderr.decode("utf8"))
```

We call `pylint` as external command with `--from-stdin` parameter to be able read file contents from stdin.
`dummy.py` may be any free filename

Output is:

```
STDOUT ------------------
************* Module dummy
dummy.py:3:21: C0303: Trailing whitespace (trailing-whitespace)
dummy.py:3:0: W0311: Bad indentation. Found 1 spaces, expected 4 (bad-indentation)
dummy.py:1:0: C0114: Missing module docstring (missing-module-docstring)
dummy.py:2:0: C0103: Function name "a" doesn't conform to snake_case naming style (invalid-name)
dummy.py:2:6: C0103: Argument name "a" doesn't conform to snake_case naming style (invalid-name)
dummy.py:2:0: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
dummy.py:2:6: W0621: Redefining name 'a' from outer scope (line 2) (redefined-outer-name)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at -25.00/10 (previous run: -25.00/10, +0.00)


STDERR ------------------
```